# Resampling with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a data set similar to following file

```
2013-05-30 06:00:41    173.199.116.171
2013-05-30 06:05:41    61.245.172.14
2013-05-30 06:10:42    74.86.158.106
2013-05-30 06:20:42    61.245.172.14
```

I want to resample it for 20 minutes and get the hit count for certain 20 minute time slot.(eg. between (06.00.00-06.20.00 or 06.40.00-07.00.00 etc.). I can print the hit count for the whole data file as follows.

```
ips = df.groupby('IP').size()
```

How to get the hit count for each 20 minute slots?Following code just print all the IPs between '06:00:00' and '06:20:00.

```
df_s = df['IP'].resample('20t', how='count')
print df['IP'].between_time('06:00:00', '06:20:00')
```

Comment: What does your df_s look like? I dont think i can replicate it with pandas 0.11. My 6:00 slot contains three hits, and my 6:20 slot 1. Have you tried setting the `closed=` and `label=` keywords? The default bins definition might be different from what you are expecting.

Comment: @Rutger Kassies How about this?But I have to specify the time slot? new = DataFrame(df['IP'].between_time('06:00:00', '06:20:00'))
t = new.groupby('IP').size()

Answer (score 2):

This is a new method available in 0.11.1 (coming very soon), providing a group filtering mechanism, thanks @DanAllen

```
In [49]: df
Out[49]: 
                                  ip
date_time                           
2013-05-30 06:00:41  173.199.116.171
2013-05-30 06:05:41    61.245.172.14
2013-05-30 06:10:42    74.86.158.106
2013-05-30 06:20:42    61.245.172.14

In [50]: df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('20min')).filter(lambda x: x.between_time('06:00:00', '06:20:00'))
Out[50]: 
                                  ip
date_time                           
2013-05-30 06:00:41  173.199.116.171
2013-05-30 06:05:41    61.245.172.14
2013-05-30 06:10:42    74.86.158.106
```

Comment: Thanks but have to wait :)! Until then I want to get IPs for every 20 min slot?Could you please suggest me a way?

Comment: @AndyHayden method below will work, or is there something else you are after?

Comment: df1.IP.between_time('06:00:00', '06:20:00') This part, I want to get automatically, I mean to print IPs for every 2o min slot staring from 06:00:00?

Answer (score 1):

The first counts all the rows from each 20 minute slot

```
In [11]: df1.IP.resample('20t', how='count')  # I usually prefer '20min'
Out[11]:
datetime
2013-05-30 06:00:00    3
2013-05-30 06:20:00    1
dtype: int64
```

The second grabs those rows between certain times:

```
In [12]: df1.IP.between_time('06:00:00', '06:20:00')
Out[12]:
datetime
2013-05-30 06:00:41    173.199.116.171
2013-05-30 06:05:41      61.245.172.14
2013-05-30 06:10:42      74.86.158.106
Name: IP, dtype: object
```

There *may* to be a neat solution to the general problem (so you don't need to specify the times between) using a TimeGrouper, but this is the best I can do, to print all of the groupings:

```
In [13]: tg = pd.TimeGrouper('20t')

In [14]: g = df1.groupby(tg)

In [15]: def f(x):
             print x
             return x

In [16]: _ = g.apply(f)                # the '_ =' bit just suppresses ouput
                                  IP
datetime
2013-05-30 06:00:41  173.199.116.171
2013-05-30 06:05:41    61.245.172.14
2013-05-30 06:10:42    74.86.158.106
                                IP
datetime
2013-05-30 06:20:42  61.245.172.14
```

Comment: Thanks Andy! 'TimeGrouper' this is important for me